# Trouble aligning a column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I am having difficulties with the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
x &= y &\mbox{(by theorem 17)}\\
&=z &\mbox{(follows from the previous page)}\\
&=0 &\mbox{(because  $z>0$)}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

The rightmost column should be aligned on the left. Instead it is aligned on the right. How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an additional alignment operator `&`, effectively inserting a zero-width left-hand side element:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x &= y && \text{(by Theorem~17)} \\
    &= z && \text{(follows from the previous page)} \\
    &= 0 && \text{(because $z>0$)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Note the space between the equations and the descriptions. If you want something closer to one another, perhaps consider using `alignat`:

[image]

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  x &= y \qquad && \text{(by Theorem~17)} \\
    &= z        && \text{(follows from the previous page)} \\
    &= 0        && \text{(because $z>0$)}
\end{alignat*}
```